# How change value data binding string with NativeScript

Tags: javascript, nativescript

I'm trying to change the value of a data binding, and make the value change on screen too, but I'm not getting it.

My `onPageLoaded`

```
export function onPageLoaded(args: EventData) {

    main = <Page>args.object;


    main.bindingContext = fromObject({
        loading: false,
        next: true,
        prev: false,
        count: 0,
        percent: 10,
        dataBoundVariable: null,
        form_hemodialysis: null,
        form_hemoderivatives: null,
        form_special_medicine: null,
        form_medicine: null,
        form_antibiotics: null,
        form_bandaid: null,
        form_speech_therapy: null,
        form_motor_therapy: null,
        form_respiratory_therapy: null,
        form_other_therapy: null,
        form: {
            patientStatus: null,
            reason: null,
            assistantDoctor: null,
            council: null,
            hospitalizationTypeId: null,
            hospitalizationDate: '6/1/2019',
            cidId: null,
            accommodationId: null,
            hda: null,
            diagnosis: null,
            speechtherapy_start_date: null,
            speechtherapy_frequency: null,
            motortherapy_start_date: null,
            motortherapy_frequency: null,
            respiratorytherapy_start_date: null,
            respiratorytherapy_frequency: null,
            othertherapy_start_date: null,
            othertherapy_frequency: null,
            procedures: [],
            antibiotics_name: null,
            antibiotics_start_date: null,
            antibiotics_end_date: null,
            antibiotics_prescription: null,
            comment: null,
            special_medicament: null,
            medicine: null,
            diets: [],
            gasotherapies: [],
            dressings: array,
            procedure
        },
        status: [
            'Alta',
            'Internado',
            'Não encontrado'
        ],
        reasons: [],
        internationTypes: [],
        accommodations: [],
        diets: [],
        cdi: ['Rafael', 'Deivid'],
        gasotherapies: [],
        bandaidPhases: ['I', 'II', 'III', 'IV'],
        bandaid: {
            phase: null,
            region: null,
            lesion_width: null,
            lesion_length: null,
            used_cover: null,
            expected_exchange: null
        },
        procedure: {
            name: null,
            date: null
        },
        statusSelected: null,
        otherDiets: false,
        otherGasotherapies: false
    })
}

export function selectDateInternacao(args){
    modalDatetimepicker = new ModalDatetimepicker();

    modalDatetimepicker
    .pickDate({
      title: "Selecione a data",
      theme: "light"
    })
    .then(result => {
        var date = `${result.day}/${result.month}/${result.year}`

        main.bindingContext.form.hospitalizationDate = date     
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(`Error: ${error}`);
    });
}
```

It is worth remembering that the value is updated, it does not change on screen, but if I give a `console.log(main.bindingContext.form.hospitalizationDate)` the value comes updated

Comment: Please share your bindingContext implementation.

Comment: Don't make `modalDatetimepicker` a global variable?

Comment: @Manoj Updated,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `fromObject({...})`, changes on the immediate properties will only be monitored. `modalDatetimepicker` is nested inside `form`, so any changes on `form` can only trigger an update on UI. You may force it using either of the syntaxes below,

**Assign a new object to form**

```
main.bindingContext.form = Object.assign({}, main.bindingContext.form, {
 hospitalizationDate: date
});
```

(Or)

**Force change detection by triggering property change event**

```
main.bindingContext.form.hospitalizationDate = date;
main.bindingContext.notifyPropertyChange('form', main.bindingContext.form);
```